# Using Vaadin grid in angular2 application

Tags: angular, vaadin-grid

I am trying to use vaadin grid in my angular2 application...As per the documentation here https://vaadin.com/download#elements i have imported webcomponents-lite.min.js , vaadin-grid.html and vaadin directive in this example http://plnkr.co/edit/B9216vP7kDlDkN44kriB?p=preview ...I dont see any errors and i dont see the grid too...can somebody please tell me what i am missing?
Here are my import statements in html

```
    <link rel="import" href="https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-core-elements/latest/vaadin-grid/vaadin-grid.html">
<script src="http://polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
```

This is the directive from the documentation

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

const Polymer = (<any>window).Polymer;

@Directive({selector: 'vaadin-grid'})
export class VaadinGrid {

@Output('grid-ready') gridReady: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter(false);

private grid: any;

 constructor(el: ElementRef) {
if (!Polymer || !Polymer.isInstance(el.nativeElement)) {
  console.error("vaadin-grid has not been registered yet, please remember to import vaadin-grid.html in your main HTML page.");
  return;
}
this.grid = el.nativeElement;
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
// Configuration <table> might be placed in a wrong container.
// Let's move it in the light dom programmatically to fix that.
var localDomTable = this.grid.querySelector("table:not(.vaadin-grid)");
if (localDomTable) {
  Polymer.dom(this.grid).appendChild(localDomTable);
}

this.grid.then(() => {
  this.gridReady.emit(this.grid);
});
 }
}
```

Is there something which i need to add more for making vaadin grid work in my angular2 app? Somebody please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it working http://plnkr.co/edit/SjoDN0zOnI88pffB31XK?p=preview

I found two issues:

1) It seems that cdn link to vaadin-grid.html isn't valid. So i copied files from bower.

2) You forgot to subscribe on WebComponentsReady event like this:

```
window.addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
  System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
});
```

Moreover, i found a good boilerplate https://github.com/vaadin/expense-manager-ng2-demo

Hope it helps you!